# not able to login into gitlab using linux system

Tags: gitlab

I can view files but I can not login into gitlab and github, it says 422 changes have been rejected.

can anyone please help me on this.

The issue I am getting on Ubuntu machine, on windows machine it is working fine.

Comment: What exactly are you doing when you get the error? Are you trying to push changes with git? accessing the website? Anything else? Please show the commands you are running and the exact error messages by editing your question.

Comment: a gitlab url or github url using browser

Comment: Did you reload the page ? It happens to me sometimes, I usually reload the page by copying/pasting the url to clear the POST request and I enter my login and password again.